# Connect-AzureAD -TenantId not showing login if run in PowerShell form

Tags: powershell, forms, azure-active-directory

My PowerShell code uses Connect-AzureAD -TenantId '********' to login to Azure AD. The code works fine.
Problem: When I use the same code in a PowerShell form, I get no error, but the sign-in applet does not show. No "External Script Driver\Sign in to your account" process in Task Manager.
What can be done to overcome this problem?

Comment: See troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-11.3.0

Comment: You should consider using a certificate or secret in order to bypass the login screen. If you don’t share more of your forms code we cannot help either.

Comment: Kindly share the complete code that you have tried?

Comment: According to Microsoft "Azure AD Powershell is planned for deprecation on March 30, 2024". What alternative is there? I tried Microsoft.Graph. It's loading very slowly and I get the error: function capacity 4096 has been exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

> Connect-AzureAD -TenantId not showing login if run in PowerShell form

I do agree with <kbd>alexzelaya</kbd> for suggesting the same point.

When using the `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId` cmdlet in `PowerShell form`, it redirects to user authentication for logging into `Azure AD`. To bypass this authentication, you can utilize a **Service Principal** to connect to `Azure AD`.

Here is the `PowerShell` script to create `PowerShell form` and establish a connection with `Azure AD`.

```
    # Create form
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "Azure AD Login Form"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,200)
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    
    # Add controls for Tenant ID
    $labelTenantId = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $labelTenantId.Text = "Enter Tenant ID:"
    $labelTenantId.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
    $labelTenantId.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($labelTenantId)
    
    $textBoxTenantId = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBoxTenantId.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,20)
    $textBoxTenantId.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBoxTenantId)
    
    # Add controls for Application Id
    $labelAppId = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $labelAppId.Text = "Enter Application ID:"
    $labelAppId.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
    $labelAppId.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($labelAppId)
    
    $textBoxAppId = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBoxAppId.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,50)
    $textBoxAppId.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBoxAppId)
    
    # Add controls for Certificate Thumbprint
    $labelCertThumbprint = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $labelCertThumbprint.Text = "Enter Certificate Thumbprint:"
    $labelCertThumbprint.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,80)
    $labelCertThumbprint.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($labelCertThumbprint)
    
    $textBoxCertThumbprint = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBoxCertThumbprint.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,80)
    $textBoxCertThumbprint.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBoxCertThumbprint)
    
    # Add button to connect
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Text = "Connect to Azure AD"
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
    $button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,30)
    $button.Add_Click({
        # Connect to Azure AD using provided details
        $tenantId = $textBoxTenantId.Text
        $appId    = $textBoxAppId.Text
        $certThumbprint = $textBoxCertThumbprint.Text
        Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -ApplicationId $appId -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint
    
        Write-Host "Connected to Azure AD with Tenant ID: $tenantId"
    })
    $form.Controls.Add($button)
    
    # Show form
    $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

**Form input page.**

[image]

After inputting the necessary details into the form, it successfully connected to `Azure AD`.

[image]